# Safari rendering different border width bug

Tags: html, css, safari

Ok, so here is the problem: I wanted to create a select+button element and everything went good, apart from one thing.

For some reason a border for "select" and a border for "a" tags are rendering in a different way. And though its a tiny detail, that you may not notice if you do not zoom, it irritates me a lot.

There is no such a problem at Chrome and Firefox, but it is visible in Safari. My guess is that I might have forgotten to override some rooted "select" styles for Safari but my experiments didn't succeed.

Would be glad for your help!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4df91z7k/)
[Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqq50.png)

HTML:

```
<li class="category-product-buttons">
  <select style="color: rgb(38, 38, 38);">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
  </select>
  <a class="button-anim" type="button" href="">Buy</a>
</li>
```

CSS is at the Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

the best bet at creating a dropdown  that looks the same on all browsers is in fact not to use a . if you can change the html and add js to your project it can be achieved with a ul or divs

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.custom-select__field').on('click', function(){
    $('.custom-select__list').toggle();
  });
  
  $('.custom-select__list li').on('click', function(){
    $('.select-value').val($(this).data('value'));
    $('.custom-select__list').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* reseting ul styles */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* styling dropdown */

.custom-select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.custom-select__field {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-select__list {
  display:none;
}

.custom-select__list li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background:rgba(125,125,0,.2);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Only showing this field as text for demonstration, you can hide it with type="hidden"<br>
<br>
<input class="select-value" name="select-value" type="text">
<br>
You can change the style and everything as you need it.<br><br>

<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="custom-select__field">Select one</div>
  <ul class="custom-select__list">
    <li data-value="1">1</li>
    <li data-value="2">2</li>
    <li data-value="3">3</li>
    <li data-value="4">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

if you have questions to the concept of this, ask away

Comment: Thank you, @Dirk. Though it didn't actually help me in this case, I completely agree with you!